# Apply dynamically defined aggregation function on array values

Tags: vba, excel

I want apply a user defined aggregation function (string-value from a certain cell, like `"SUM"` or `"STDEV"`) on an array of values. Here's a simplified example. However I don't know how to make the aggregation (last line):

```
Sub test()
    Dim values() As Double
    ReDim values(1 To 3)
    values(1) = 3.5
    values(2) = 5
    values(3) = 4.8

    Dim aggregate_fn As String
    aggregate_fn = "SUM"       

    Dim result As Double
    result = Evaluate("=" & aggregate_fn & "(" & values & ")")  ' <-- This doesn't work, but hopefully it's clear what it should do

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

My original code is also creating the `values` array dynamically from a spreadsheet which uses `,` as decimal sign. This causes an issue with Scott's answer below.

```
Const datasht = "Daten"
Const aggregate_cell = "G1"

Sub run()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim n_rows As Integer
    Dim rw As Integer

    Application.DecimalSeparator = "."

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(datasht)
    n_rows = sht.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count  ' Get range of data

    Dim values() As String
    ReDim values(1 To n_rows)

    For rw = 1 To n_rows
        values(rw) = sht.Cells(rw, 1).Value
    Next rw
    Debug.Print (aggregate(values))

End Sub

Function aggregate(values() As String)
    ' Get aggregated value
    Dim aggregate_fn As String
    aggregate_fn = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(datasht).Range(aggregate_cell).Value
    aggregate = Evaluate("=" & aggregate_fn & "(" & Join(values, ",") & ")") ' <-- doesn't work as intended

End Function
```

Comment: Use `Join(values,",")` instead of `values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for any function available via `Application.WorksheetFunction`, and is less likely to give an error if you pass too many values.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr(0 To 1000), res, x As Long, f as String

    'get some values to work with...
    For x = 0 To 1000
        arr(x) = Rnd() * 10
    Next x

    f = "SUM"

    res = CallByName(Application.WorksheetFunction, f, VbMethod, arr)

    Debug.Print res

End Sub
```

Comment: This also works correctly if the application's decimal sign is `,`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by creating a string from your array, then using that instead:

```
Sub test()

    Dim values() As Double
    ReDim values(1 To 3)
    values(1) = 3.5
    values(2) = 5
    values(3) = 4.8

    Dim mystring As String, i As Long
    mystring = values(LBound(values))

    For i = LBound(values) + 1 To UBound(values)
        mystring = mystring & "," & values(i)
    Next i

    Dim aggregate_fn As String
    aggregate_fn = "SUM"

    Dim result As Double
    result = Evaluate("=" & aggregate_fn & "(" & mystring & ")")

    Debug.Print result

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: @LatafaShi Added picture above - cannot reproduce your results.

Answer (score 1):

Join works with Strings change the values to String instead of Double:

```
Sub test()
    Dim values() As String
    ReDim values(1 To 3)
    values(1) = 3.5
    values(2) = 5
    values(3) = 4.8

    Dim aggregate_fn As String
    aggregate_fn = "SUM"

    Dim result As Double
    result = Evaluate("=" & aggregate_fn & "(" & Join(values, ",") & ")")
    Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

[image]

---

As per your edit there is no need for the array at all, just pass the range and worksheet to the function and use `.Address` on the range.

```
Const datasht = "Daten"
Const aggregate_cell = "G1"

Sub run()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim n_rows As Integer
    Dim rw As Integer

    'Application.DecimalSeparator = "."

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(datasht)
    n_rows = sht.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count  ' Get range of data

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(n_rows, 1))

    Debug.Print (aggregate(sht, rng))

End Sub

Function aggregate(sht As Worksheet, rng As Range)
    ' Get aggregated value
    Dim aggregate_fn As String
    aggregate_fn = sht.Range(aggregate_cell).Value
    aggregate = sht.Evaluate("=" & aggregate_fn & "(" & rng.Address(1, 1) & ")") 
End Function
```

Comment: @LatifaShi not sure why yours is different unless you are using `,` instead of `.` that vba requires.

Comment: Same for me. `Join(values, ",")` result in `3,5,5,4,8` if you have `,` as decimal sign. Do you know how to change decimal sign during runtime of the procedure?

Comment: @ascripter you need to show then how you are loading the array in the first place.  Because as per your question you are putting the values in directly in EN-US format.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah so the issue on my end was the array being declared a `Double`...

Comment: @Scott I read the values from certain cells of a spreadsheet which have `,` decimal. I tried setting `Application.DecimalSeparator = "."`, but this doesn't change the case.

Comment: @dwirony declaring it as a string makes it work with `Join`  it does not fix the issue that the OP is loading the array with numbers that use `,` instead of `.` as the decimal separator.

Comment: @ascripter please edit your original post and show how you are loading the array.

Comment: @ascripter Just loop through array `LBound(values) to UBound(values)`, `values(i) = Replace(values(i), ",", ".")`.

Comment: @dwirony there are quicker methods depending on how the array is loaded.  `.Value2` comes to mind, but again it depends on how the array is being loaded.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I see... so if he's loading a range to the array he can just use `Range.Value2`?

Comment: @dwirony but if the OP is loading a consecutive range then skip the whole array and just use: `result = Worksheet("Sheet1").Evaluate(aggregate_fn & "(" & Range("A1:A3").Address(1,1) & ")")`  that is why I want to see how the array is being loaded, it may  be unnecessary.

Comment: @ascripter also you know that Excel has an aggregate function that you can pass a number to that will change the output?